# как обновить состояние ListView.builder()?

Tags: flutter

я хотел передать значение `List<Map<String,String>>` в `ListView.builder()` и вывести его на экран и в каждой ячейке добавить две кнопки, добавить ячейку после данной ячейки и удалить данную ячейку, проблема в том что по факту добавляются и удаляются они правильно, а вот выводятся добавленные ячейки как последняя ячейка, как это можно исправить?

p.s: Попробовал при нажатии кнопок `Navigator.pushReplacement()...` но это не то и позиция страницы в этом случае теряется

вот мой код:

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'data/data.dart';
_AddPageState state = _AddPageState();

    class AddPage extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      _AddPageState createState() => _AddPageState();
    }

    class _AddPageState extends State<AddPage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Ән қосу'),
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.save,
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {},
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                          title: Column(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              TextFormField(
                                initialValue: data[index]['data'],
                              ),
                              TextFormField(
                                initialValue: data[index]['text']
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                          subtitle: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 50,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      addBeforeIndex(data, index);
                                      print(json.encode(data));
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 50,
                                child: IconButton(
                                  icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    setState(() {
                                      setState(() {
                                        removeIndex(index);
                                        print(json.encode(data));
                                      });
                                    });
                                  },
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ));
                    },
                  ),
        );
      }
    }
```

а вот код из `data.dart` :

```
List<Map<String, String>> data = [
  {"data": "data1", "text": "text1"},
  {"data": "data2", "text": "text2"},
  {"data": "data3", "text": "text3"}
];
Map<String, String> inData = {"data": "", "text": ""};



void add(List data) {
  Map<String, String> v = inData;
  data.add(v);
}

void addBeforeIndex(List data, int index) {
  Map<String, String> v = inData;
  data.insert(index+1, v);
}

void removeIndex(int index) {
  data.removeAt(index);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прочитайте что такое [Key](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets-intro#keys) и как с ним работать.

Исправил код, добавил `key: new Key(data.length.toString())` *(это временное решение, думайте как сделать правильно, отталкиваясь от вашей архитектуры.)*:

```
class AddPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddPageState createState() => _AddPageState();
}

class _AddPageState extends State<AddPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Ән қосу'),
        centerTitle: true,
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.save,
              size: 30.0,
            ),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        key: new Key(data.length.toString()),
        itemCount: data.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return ListTile(
              title: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  TextFormField(
                    initialValue: data[index]['data'],
                  ),
                  TextFormField(initialValue: data[index]['text'])
                ],
              ),
              subtitle: Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 50,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.add),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          addBeforeIndex(data, index);
                          print(json.encode(data));
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 50,
                    child: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.remove),
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          removeIndex(index);
                          print(json.encode(data));
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```